# How to create a Сharacter Сontrol script based on specific numeric variables?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am not an experienced programmer, especially in Unity and c#. But I found a unity project on GitHub (https://github.com/hubertgdev/mindwave-unity) in which, using the Neurosky Mindwave 2 BCI device, you can control the explosion of a bomb. I have this BCI and everything is connected. Values (integers) of attention and meditation are used to make the bomb explode or the wick will go out. I thought that by using similar logic,  I can move the character using the values ​​​​of attention and meditation.

For example, if attention >= 75 -> character moves forward. If attention <= 40 -> character moves reverse. If meditation >= 75 -> character moves to the right, If meditation <= 40 -> character moves to the left.

I created a simple game that has a capsule on a flat map. The simplest script for movement using the WASD buttons is linked to the capsule.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float _moveSpeed = 5f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float _gravity = 9.81f;

    private CharacterController _controller;

    void Start()
    {
        _controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

    }

    void Update()
    {
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0, verticalInput);

    
      
        direction.y -= _gravity;


        _controller.Move(direction * _moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I was also able to connect the MindwaveManager element, which allows me to connect my BCI to the game and display all the data in real-time on the screen.

Thanks to the author of the github repository, I have all the necessary scripts, but due to the lack of experience and knowledge, I have absolutely no idea how to use them correctly to create the character control method I conceived. With this I need help.

It is also known that data from BCI gets to the program in the form of dataModel with `int` values ​​related to different brain waves, such as Delta, theta, lowalpha, highalpha, lowbeta, highbeta, lowgamma, HighGamma.(see github) But I haven't seen (due to lack of knowledge) how author created the Focus and Meditation variables used script for activating bomb.

If you need more information, please use the GitHub link, because I cannot put all the scripts here... the main scripts are located in the path `Assets\Demo\Scipts` and `Assets\Plugins\MindwaveUnity\Core`  and they have useful comments.

I would appreciate it if you could show me how to create such a character control script.

Answer (score 1):

The formula below will help you to move the character according to the above definition.

```cs
[SerializeField]
private float _moveSpeed = 5f;
[SerializeField]
private float _gravity = 9.81f;

[Range(0, 75)]
[SerializeField] private float attention;
[Range(0, 75)]
[SerializeField] private float meditation;

private CharacterController _controller;
void Start()
{
    _controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void Update()
{
    // axis calculation formula
    var z = Mathf.Clamp((attention - 40) / 35, -1f, 1f);
    var x = Mathf.Clamp((meditation - 40) / 35, -1f, 1f);
    
    // Set transform to local scape
    var direction = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(x, 0, z));
    _controller.Move(direction * (_moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
}
```

Comment: It's almost what I wanted. You give me an idea of what to do, thank you! But for some reason character moves forward right after starting the game, do you know why?

Comment: @AlexanderUrum Try to change the values and see the result, also make sure that the local z axis is in front of your character.